# data-type="search" inputs and the default text

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I look at the HTML generated by jquery mobile, I see:

```
<input placeholder="Filter Items..." data-type="search" class="ui-input-text ui-body-b">
```

My attempt to change this value:

```
$("ul[data-filter='true'], input[data-type='search']").attr("placeholder", "Testing...");
```

I need to do this dynamically in javascript due to language files.

Yet, the change doesn't apply! I'm using many other similar methods to translate my pages, it's only these search boxes that don't work.

Comment: Try inverting your single and double quotes; you never know. But maybe Jquery doesn't know data-type. Try selecting with a class/ID and see if it works. If so, then Jquery doesn't know data-type, so you need to select it otherwise. <input type="search"> exists, for example, so you could use that. Or just anything else that'll allow you to select your inputs apart from data-filter and data-type.

Comment: Are you including the code inside `DOM ready` handler

Answer (score 1):

Give an `id` to the `input` field and change the `placeholder` value as below

```
$("#input").attr("placeholder", "Testing...");
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RhVuZ/)

If you want to use `attr` selector than do this

```
$('input[data-type="search"]').attr("placeholder", "Testing...");
```